# Prevent SSH from freezing in less than a minute

Tags: ubuntu, mac, ssh

I have a problem with my SSH session freezing predictably in less than minute.  There is no warning, no errors, to way to get out of it.  It doesn't seem to be a timeout issue since it happens when I'm in the middle of editing a file with vi (as an example).

Here's what I've tried:
1.  Connect from home on Macbook ----> predictable freeze within a minute.
2.  Connect from home on Ubuntu 9.10 server box ----> predictable freeze within a minute.
3.  Connect from another network on same Macbook above ----> works fine.

It sounds to me like there must be something weird with my router or internet connection.  But when this happens, I might also have a VPN connection up and an RDP session going, and both stay up and running.  I would have then thought it was my webhost, but no one else is having any trouble (and it worked fine from another network).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by unplugging the Linksys WRV200 router and plugging in an old Linksys router I bought back in 2002. No more problems.  If someone has any advice on what it is about that router (or a particular default setting) that would cause this problem I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

How's your router configured? Port forwarding? NAT?

Comment: It's basically just configured as a standard Linksys VPN router.  I'm not doing any special port forwarding.

Comment: Is the router behind a DSL modem? Maybe you just need to disable NAT.

Comment: The router is behind a WISP antenna.  But this is the side running the SSH client.  The server is a web hosting provider.  I don't believe I've ever needed to disable NAT from the client side to enable SSH.